# What are the conditions on the components of b such that b $ \in$ col(A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let **b** = $(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)^T$ $\in$ $R^4$.

Let $A$ = $\left[
       \begin{array}{ccc}
       -1&-3&1&1&\\
       3&8&-2&1& \\
       -2&-8&4&6&\\
    -7&-19&5&3&\\ 
       \end{array}
\right]$
and the row echelon form of $[A|b]$ be:

(R|**y**) =
$\left[
       \begin{array}{cccc|c}
       -1&-3&1&1&b_1\\
       0&-1&1&2&3b_1+b_2 \\
       0&0&0&0&-8b_1-2b_2+b_3\\
    0&0&0&0&-b_1+2b_2+b_4\\ 
       \end{array}
\right]$

i) What are the conditions on the components of **b** such that **b** $ \in$ col(A)?

I tried to let $x_3$ and $x_4$ be some free variable, but I don't think it's asking for the span of something.

ii) Find a matrix $C$ such that col(A) = ker(C).

Answer (score 0):

You get something much simpler if you work with vectors instead of components of vectors:

> > For any $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and any $b\in\Bbb R^m$: $b\in col(A)$ if and only if $Ax=b$ has a solution.

(So: Find an echelon form for the augmented matrix $[A|b]$; there is a solution if and only if the echelon form does not have a row of the form $[0|c]$ with $c\ne0$. Assuming you got the echelon form for $[A|b]$ right this answers your question for the specific $A$ you ask about.)

(ii) Saying $row(A)\subset\ker(C)$ says precisely that every row of $A$ is orthogonal to every column of $C$, which is to say that every column of $C$ lies in $\ker(A^T)$. So: If $c_1,\dots, c_k$ is a basis for $\ker(A^T)$ then letting $C$ be the matrix with columns $c_1,\dots,c_k$ should work.

Comment: My bad, I have since edited in A.